# Only filter my time in SQL Server where clause

Tags: sql-server, datetime, where-clause

I am new to SQL and Programming in general. I have a datetime field which I want to use to filter my results but only on the time portion.

For example I need to run a report from 2pm yesterday to 7am current day. I cannot hard code the dates because this report needs to run daily. This Query will run from a stored procedure automatically.

I have tried AND clm.createDtTm > DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE()), which goes back one day but not the time range I need.

I tried this: AND (datepart(hh, '11:02:54.107') = 7)<--To be honest not even sure what I am doing here.

I am not sure if this is even possible, but if I can get results for one day back I am assuming there has to be a way to narrow that day between hours.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Abdul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, it filters out rows that do not fall in the date interval, from 7pm yesterday to 7am today.

```
WHERE
    createDtTm >= DATEADD(HOUR, 14,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATETIME))
    AND createDtTm <= DATEADD(HOUR, 7, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: Thanks Jesus this helps a lot, and I learned something new. I believe it works but I don't have test data in my dev environment for it pull back any data. Will have to test it after creating some test data.

Comment: I tested it, both expressions give you the expected results.

Comment: Hi Jesus, can this be done by doing a case statement so It can be in one query? something like:      AND     CASE
        WHEN  DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) + '18:00'= GETDATE()
        THEN clm.createDtTm >= DATEADD(HOUR, 14,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATETIME))
  AND  clm.createDtTm <= DATEADD(HOUR, 7, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
        ELSE -9999 -- Some numeric value that just cannot exist in the column
    END

Comment: Yes, you can..., but you shouldn't. When you enclose columns in expressions you prevent SQL Server from using indexes. You should write your predicates in where clauses like: ColumnName operator Expression to allow SQL Server to use indexes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
SELECT(DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()))
  FROM table
 WHERE (DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE())) = rowloadtimestamp
HAVING DATEPART(HH,rowloadtimestamp) BETWEEN 13 AND 24

UNION

SELECT GETDATE()
  FROM table
 WHERE GETDATE() = rowloadtimestamp
HAVING DATEPART(HH,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
```

Assuming you have a rowloadtimestamp field this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with „I can not hardcode the dates” ? Do you mean the time interval is variable, or is it fixed, or are you referring to the exact dates? I'm not sure I understand.

In case of MySQL you can do something like:

```
SELECT data, date FROM table WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

This Query will get you the last two days. You can vary the interval by replacing the „2” with a variable if that is possible in your case.